# (:visible) selector not working in jQuery + Jest

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jestjs

I want to write some test on my JS project that somewhere uses jQuery selector like this:

```
 $('textarea:visible').each((idx, el) => {
     ....
 })
```

But some weird issues happened to it and the test did not find any visible textarea!

**Test file:**

```
test('renders correctly', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <textarea style="width:100px;height:100px;display:block;opacity:1;visibility:visible;">
        Test
    </textarea>
  `;
  console.log($('textarea').val()); // return Test

  console.log($('body').is(':hidden')); // return true!
  console.log($('textarea').is(':visible')); // return false!
  console.log($('textarea:visible').length); // return 0!

  ....
});
```

Comment: `is(':visible')` not `is('visible')`. Voting to close as a typo. Also your last console.log returns `1`, not `0`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/10yp4z2x/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited my question, but still, the issue happened to me. And about the last `console.log`, yes I think it should be 1! but it returns 0!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan notice the problem has occurred only in jest! So your `jsfiddle` link is pointless.

Comment: If you add `console.log($('textarea').length);` what value do you get? Is the `<textarea>` even being detected regardless of visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because since [1.3.2 jQuery's visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) is defined on whether an elements takes up space rather than just its display value.

In [jQuery 3](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js) the visible pseudo selector look like this:

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.visible = function( elem ) {
     return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
};
```

So you can rewrite [getClientReats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) like this

```
window.Element.prototype.getClientRects = function() {
    var node = this;
    while(node) {
        if(node === document) {
            break;
        }
        if (!node.style || node.style.display === 'none' || node.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
            return [];
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
     var self = $(this);
    return [{width: self.width(), height: self.height()}];
};
```